# MIME encoding of a PDF file in an HTML page

Tags: html

Can a PDF be MIME encoded and included as part of the payload of an HTML page?
This site shows that you can include a MIME-encoded image or a CSS in an HTML page:
http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64/
-- but I don't know what the markup would be for an encoded PDF included in an HTML page.  Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try it `data:application/pdf;base64,base64encodedpdf`, also what tag would you put it in?

Comment: Checkout this question and accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/best-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html

Answer (score 33):

I've tried it with `iframe` and `embed`, worked in chrome, opera and safari, no ie or ff

```
<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,base64encodedpdf"></iframe>
<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,base64encodedpdf">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yLx2W/
http://jsfiddle.net/yLx2W/1/

Maybe with some tweaking you can get them to work for ff and maybe ie.

Comment: Works in FF but not in IE.

Comment: UPDATE: As of April 2021, `iframe` works in Chrome but `embed` does not.

Comment: @JeremyW using Chrome 96.0, `embed` works for me.