# Embed a blob to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I have a pdf blob like below, not complete:
result: "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjcKCjQgMCBvYmoKKElkZW50aXR5KQplbmRvYmoKNSAwIG9iagooQWRvYmUpCmVuZG9iago4IDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9GaWx0ZXIgL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlCi9MZW5ndGggODg0OTIKL1R5cGUgL1N0cmVhbQo+PgpzdHJlYW0KeJzsfQlgVNXV…".

I need to view this pdf in html . Is there a possibility?
Please favour

Comment: did you try anything so far?

Comment: i totally have no clue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MIME encoding of a PDF file in an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551197/mime-encoding-of-a-pdf-file-in-an-html-page)

Comment: @MehravishTemkar it gave me Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
    at DomSanitizerImpl.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DomSanitizerImpl.sanitize (platform-browser.js:1812)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js), refer to this [example](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/learning/helloworld64.html), it's pretty straightforward :)

Answer (score 0):

This is solved with embed tag in html,  as in "[MIME encoding of a PDF file in an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551197/mime-encoding-of-a-pdf-file-in-an-html-page)".

This resulted in error

> "Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see
>   g.co/ng/security#xss) at
>   DomSanitizerImpl.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DomSanitizerImpl.sanitize
>   (platform-browser.js:1812)"

This was later solved with [Unsafe value used in a resource URL context with Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927657/unsafe-value-used-in-a-resource-url-context-with-angular-2/38079724) using DomSanitizer, answered by @helzgate as method 1.

Overall code:

in HTML:

```
<embed [src]='sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(imgURL)' height="200" *ngIf="imgURL">
```

In typescript,add the following in component:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

and

```
  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
```