# Viewing Base64 Pdf and Image In React

Tags: reactjs, pdf

How can I view pdfs and images in react which is base64 format. I am trying to use same component for all formats.

[image]

Comment: Images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html

PDF's: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551197/mime-encoding-of-a-pdf-file-in-an-html-page

Comment: but i want same component or library for pdf and images(jpeg etc.) @KiprasT

Comment: The LEADTOOLS SDK (Disclaimer:  I work for the vendor) has an [Image Viewer]( https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/display) that can be used to load and display image and PDF in ReactJS (After decoding them from base64). You can find a tutorial [here]( https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/tutorials/html5-reactjs-display-images-in-an-imageviewer.html) showing how this can be done with the toolkit hit and if it interests you, a free evaluation is available here [here](https://leadtools.com/downloads).